# How can I inherit and override a third party class method, to extend it's functionality?

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

I need to override a class method from a third party module, which we will call `foo`. `foo` has a method `post()` that calls upon another method `create_object()` that I would like to override, and extend it's functionality:

`foo.py`

```
class Foo():
    def create_object():
        return 'Creating object 1'

    def post(self):
        result = self.create_object()
```

`bar.py`

```
class Bar(Foo):
    def create_object(self):
        return 'Creating object 2'
```

When `foo`'s `post()` method is called, I would like that to re-direct to `bar`'s `create_object()` method instead. Is there a way I can interrupt the normal process get my method called instead?

Comment: Why don't you create an instance of `Bar` and go from there?

Comment: When working with this third party module, it basically does it's own thing, and I need to intercept the `create_object()` method without editing the module itself. So I have my `Bar` class set up in my own module with the `create_object()` method, and I need to somehow call it.

Answer (score 1):

Followed this article here: https://tryolabs.com/blog/2013/07/05/run-time-method-patching-python/

Updated code is as follows:

`foo.py`

```
class Foo():
    def create_object():
        return 'Creating object 1'

    def post(self):
        result = self.create_object()
```

`bar.py`

```
class Bar(Foo):

    def create_object(self):
        return 'Creating object 2'

    def run(self):
        Foo.create_object = self.create_object
```